# GPSTracker can not resolve in android studio

Tags: android, gps, build.gradle

i starting new project on android studio and i finding my location using below code.

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {



      GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(RegisterActivity.this);
        gpsTracker.canGetLocation();
        strLattitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude() + "";
        strLongitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude() + "";



    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                "This app requires GPS. Please enable location access",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

but i have no idea how to solve this problem. i also add google play service libarary in android studio.

build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.eheuristic.ordersin"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
        compile project(':httpmime-4.0.1')
        compile project(':apache-mime4j-0.6')
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle please

Comment: Please remove  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'

Comment: it still not resolve or import GPSTracker.

Comment: Add this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: thanks @IntelliJAmiya i also put this permission but in java code there in one problem when focus my cursor on GPSTracker that time display one pop up like "can not resolve symbol 'GPSTracker' ".

Comment: Check another usefull link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888995/i-m-trying-to-develop-an-android-app-to-get-the-location-using-googleapi-but-it

Comment: apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

        LocationManager locationManager ;
        String provider;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.xxxx);

            // Getting LocationManager object
            locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating an empty criteria object
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the provider that meets the criteria
            provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

            if(provider!=null && !provider.equals("")){

                // Get the location from the given provider
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 1, this);

                if(location!=null)
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Getting reference to TextView tv_longitude
            TextView tvLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);

            // Getting reference to TextView tv_latitude
            TextView tvLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);

            // Setting Current Longitude
            tvLongitude.setText("Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

            // Setting Current Latitude
            tvLatitude.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() );
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
```

Your XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_longitude"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_latitude"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_longitude"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Here is OP

[image]

Comment: why not implement LocationListener listner ? is there any android studio problem ?

Comment: Are you using android studio ?

Comment: Set this in your manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: thanks @IntelliJ Amiya , i also put both permission but it still not working.

Comment: Print long,lat using Log.D("",);

Comment: how can run my project without solving this issue ?

Comment: How can this possible .I am using Android Studio .Please enable your LOCATION SERVICE (DEVICE) .

Comment: Don't need compile project(':httpmime-4.0.1')
        compile project(':apache-mime4j-0.6')
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87' if you use my code. Because i run this on Android Studio .Happy coding